# 'Movie not loaded.." IE6 using swfobject2.2

Tags: javascript, xhtml, internet-explorer-6, flashplayer-10

I'm getting and error that only occurs with IE6 using swfobject to dynamically embed flash on a page.

I could post some code if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a very similar issue while using swfobject and MultiIE to run ie6 in Windows XP. I think I solved it by using an admin enabled user account on Windows XP.